# NSArray of values, want to display alphabetically in sections. How to distribute in correct sections?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

Sorry, I'm not sure how to search for the answer to this, but I'm sure it's out there.

I have a large NSArray of strings in alphabetical order. I want to add them to a uitableview and have them distributed correctly in each section by the first letter. I have the sections set up, but I'm not sure how to tell my tableview to add to the next section when the object starts with the next letter in the alphabet. Thanks for any help! It's much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hy

You must parse the array manually, and then tell the tableView - via delegate method - the number of sections, and items. If I were you, I would place it in a dictionary, and the keys are numbers, which are represents sections, and the values are an array of the titles. It is easy to use. You only have to parse the original array.

Comment: You could also create a "dope vector" -- an array of 26 ints (well, make that 27, with one to mark the end point) where each int tells you where in the original array the letter of the alphabet starts.  The difference between adjacent dope vector entries tells you how many items for that letter.

Comment: Metalmi, this worked perfectly for me! Thanks! Even if it was a bit tedious.

Answer (score 3):

There is an example that describes what you want:
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43374/1763

Answer (score 1):

I think using an `NSDictionary` is much more convenient in this case. An `NSDictionary` inherently allows you to store your data alphabetically.

[Vocabulous](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Vocabulous.zip) is a great example project for this use case.

Comment: No, `NSDictionary` is an unordered set of key/value pairs. It's still useful for splitting an array into sections, but too many people have the mistaken idea that the keys in a `NSDictionary` are ordered.